# is there anything like substr_replace in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, function

I have column data that looks like this "132154646878"
And i would like replace a part of each one from a specified position
something like :

> substr_replace("132154646878","***",4)
>
> Output => 132***646878

Any functions in MySQL?

Comment: If you only need to output you can use SUBSTRING 2 times and CONCAT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for MySQL's `INSERT` function.

```
INSERT(str, pos, len, newstr)
```

> Returns the string str, with the substring beginning at position pos
>   and len characters long replaced by the string newstr. Returns the
>   original string if pos is not within the length of the string.
>   Replaces the rest of the string from position pos if len is not within
>   the length of the rest of the string. Returns NULL if any argument is
>   NULL.

source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_insert

**Query**

```
SELECT INSERT("132154646878", 4, LENGTH('***'), "***");
```

**p.s keep in mind that when you use multibyte characters charset like utf8 in the newstr parameter you need to use `CHAR_LENGTH()` instead off `LENGTH()`**

**Result**

```
| INSERT("132154646878", 4, LENGTH('***'), "***") |
| ----------------------------------------------- |
| 132***646878                                    |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4aZvTSs8kmSH2tZ2uFQrUP/0)

Comment: Instead of `Length` function, shouldn't we be using `Character_length` function ?

Comment: True if the newstr parameter charset is  multibyte like utf8 you should be using `CHAR_LENGTH()` instead @MadhurBhaiya